# Как получить данные в виде json из запроса к API Озона?

Tags: python, api, requests

В [документации Ozonа](https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/) указано, что все запросы POST, но мне нужно получить только данные об отчётах. И что бы на выходе был json.

```
import requests
import json


def get_data():


headers = {
    "Host": "api-seller.ozon.ru",
    "Client-Id": "XXXX",
    "Api-Key": "XXXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "language": "DEFAULT"
}

url = requests.post("https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/product/certificate/status/list", headers=headers, data=data)

print(url.text)
```

При выполнении этого запроса на получение Отчёта об остатках получаю следующий ответ:

```
{"result":{"code":"XXXX"}}
```

Каким образом можно получить на запрос ответ с полными данными?

Answer (score 2):

Я смог решить свою проблему, следующий код делает то, что мне нужно, получает данные из отчёта:

```
import requests
import json
import time


def get_data_ozon():
    
    headers = {
        "Host": "api-seller.ozon.ru",
        "Client-Id": "XXXX",
        "Api-Key": "XXXX",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    get_url = "https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/report/stock/create"
    
    json_data = {"language": "DEFAULT"}

    # Получение кода который используется как json для второго запроса
    id_code = requests.post(get_url,headers=headers, json=json_data).json()

    # Поскольку сервер отвечает не моментально необходимо делать задержку перед вторым запросом
    time.sleep(1)

    # Получение информации об отчёте
    resp_data = requests.post("https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/report/info", headers=headers, json=id_code["result"]).json()
    # print(resp_data)

    # Файл с необходимыми данными
    # csv_file = requests.get(resp_data["result"]["file"]).text
      
get_data_ozon()
```

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами разобрались :)

Comment: Кст, используйте сессии в `requests`, чтобы можно было заголовки один раз заполнить и больше не указывать: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0f4b9f99769642b487b8ee1edd5deac2a6a0cb17/Elden%20Ring/common.py#L12

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Результат - json в виде словаря словарей

Распарсить ответ можно через [метод json](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
data = url.json()
```

А код извлекайте по ключам словаря:

```
print(data["result"]["code"])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я имел ввиду, что информация в ответе на запрос не та, что предполагалась, сейчас приходит "code": "426a02-0d20-445-ada0-be91ba15d",  а я предполагаю, что на выходе должен быть json условно "stock" : {"sku": "1234567", "warehouse_name":"SAMARA_RFC", ... , "goods_balance": "10"}, как если бы я выгружал это вручную в excel файл

Comment: Я предполагаю, что код который приходит в ответе нужен для другого запроса, но я не уверен..

Comment: @Rett_oo, поменяйте в запросе `data=data` на `json=data`. В первом случае формат запрос будет `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, а не `application/json`. И, кст, не увидел чтобы у `v1/product/certificate/status/list` был такой параметр https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#operation/CertificateStatusList . Я бы лучше убрал его из запроса

Comment: Да, с методом я ошибся. Имел ввиду "https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/report/stock/create". Я как обычно плохо прочитал документацию. Там было написано: "При запросе любого из отчётов сначала возвращается код на создание документа. Отправьте его в запросе метода /v1/report/info — в ответе вернётся файл отчёта и дополнительная информация." Сделав новый запрос, появилась другая проблема: "'code': 3, 'message': "invalid character '5' in literal false (expecting 'a')", 'details': []" ..